Functional derivative different when constraints are explicitly substituted vs. Lagrange multiplier method
Question (brief)
Is the result the same if one 1) takes a functional derivative on a constrained subspace, or 2) takes a functional derivative using the method of Lagrange multipliers to encode constraints.
Clarification and specific example
Suppose I have a field $\mathbf{Q}: M_{3\times 3}(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)) \to M_{3\times 3}(C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3))$ subject to the following constraints:
$$
\mathbf{Q} - \mathbf{Q}^T = 0
$$
and
$$
\text{Tr}(\mathbf{Q}) = 0
$$
Suppose also that I have a functional:
$$
F = \int dV f(\mathbf{Q}, \nabla \mathbf{Q})
$$
I can think of two ways to minimize $F$ by taking a functional derivative.
One is by explicitly encoding the constraints into $\mathbf{Q}$ like:
$$
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1 &Q_2 &Q_3 \\\\
Q_2 &Q_4 &Q_5 \\\\
Q_3 &Q_5 &-(Q_1 + Q_4)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for independent fields $Q_i \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, and then finding the zeros of all of the functional derivatives $\delta F / \delta Q_i = 0$.
Alternatively one could define another functional which encodes constraints into Lagrange multipliers:
$$
G = \int dV \left[ f(\mathbf{Q}, \nabla \mathbf{Q}) - \lambda \text{Tr}(\mathbf{Q}) - \lambda_i \epsilon_{ijk} Q_{jk} \right]
$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol and repeated indices are summed.
Then one may minimize by finding the zeros the functional derivatives of $G$ with respect to each of the entries of $\mathbf{Q}$: $\delta G / \delta Q_{ij} = 0$, taking $\lambda$ and $\lambda_i$ to be such that $\delta G / \delta Q_{ij}$ is traceless and symmetric.
The question is then, is the following true?
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta Q_1} = \frac{\delta G}{\delta Q_{11}}
$$
Taking $f = Q_{ij} Q_{ij}$ would seem to imply "no", because:
$$
F = 2 \left( Q_1^2 + Q_2^2 + Q_3^2 + Q_4^2 + Q_5^2 + Q_1 Q_4 \right)
$$
indicating
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta Q_1} = 4 Q_1 + 2 Q_4
$$
while
$$
\frac{\delta G}{\delta Q_{11}} = 2 Q_{11} = 2 Q_1
$$
This runs contrary to my intuition, because $\delta F / \delta Q_i$ gives the direction of steepest descent in the subspace, while $\delta F / \delta Q_{ij}$ gives the direction of steepest descent in the full space and then subtracting the Lagrange multiplier terms projects the result to be tangent to the subspace.
Is it possible that the latter operation does not give the direction of steepest descent?
I recognize that this is not at all rigorous (I am a physicist), and that my example is contrived (the minimal field value is $Q_{ij} = 0$ everywhere, but any help is appreciated!

Your formula for the derivative for $G$ can't be right because it doesn't contain any Lagrange multipliers. Also, you should have a scalar field $\lambda$ for the trace constraint as well as a matrix field $\Lambda$ for the symmetry constraint since the constraint takes on pointwise matrix values.

@whpowell96 Excuse me, I should've been more explicit. In my formula for $G$ I've computed the Lagrange multipliers to be such that the derivative of $G$ is tangent to the subspace of traceless, symmetric tensors (they happen to be zero in this case). The symmetry constraint is encoded into a vector field $\lambda_i$ through the Levi-Civita tensor. That is, $\lambda_i \epsilon_{ijk}$ is an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ antisymmetric tensor.

I believe this problem stems from the fact that these two derivatives are not being evaluated at the same matrix and are not defined on the same spaces. For the $F$ characterization, you are not actually computing any matrix derivatives at all. You have parameterized your constraint set via a vector field of $5$ functions $V= (Q_1,\dots,Q_5)^T$. This means that the gradient of the parameterization functional (termed a reduced functional) will include an extra term from the chain rule. If we denote this parameterization by $P$, where $P:C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^5)\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3})$, then the gradient is actually given by
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial V} = \left.\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q} \right|_{Q = P(V)} \left.\frac{\partial P}{\partial V} \right|_{V}.
$$
Now if we want just the derivative with respect to $Q_1$, we notice that the first factor in this product is the linear map $A\mapsto 2A_{ij}Q_{ij}$. The $Q_1$ component of the second factor is going to be
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial Q_1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Combining these yields $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q_1} = 2(Q_1) - 2(-Q_1 - Q_4) = 4Q_1 + 2Q_4$, as you obtained.
These gradients do give the direciton of steepest descent in the 5-dimensional coordinates. That is, if you only consider matrices parameterized in exactly this way, then these directions yield the steepest descent in those coordinates (basis). This discrepancy is a consequence of choice of coordinates, which is non-unique. Notice that in your supposed equality between the two derivatives, there is no guarantee that they are being evaluated at the same matrix!
Also, I will demonstrate the actual gradient of the Lagrangian. I will use $\lambda$ to denote the scalar field multiplier for the trace constraint and $\Lambda$ to denote the matrix field multiplier for the symmetry constraint. We don't even have to know that anti-symmetric matrices are tanget to the space of symmetric matrices. It is easier to do these computations using the Frobenius inner product, but I will just state the results. The Lagrangian is
$$
L(Q,\lambda,\Lambda) = Q_{ij}Q_{ij} + \lambda Q_{ii} + \Lambda_{ij}(Q_{ij}-Q_{ji})
$$
and the gradient of the corresponding functional is
$$
\nabla_QG = 2Q + \lambda I + \Lambda - \Lambda^T.
$$
The stationarity condition says this must be zero, which allows us to solve for $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$. Taking the trace and applying the map $A\mapsto A^T-A$ yields $\lambda = -\frac{2}{3}\mathrm{tr}(Q)$ and $\Lambda = Q^T - Q$. The gradient is then give by
$$
\nabla_Q G = 2Q - \frac{2}{3}\mathrm{tr}(Q)I + 2Q^T - 2Q.
$$
Here we can see the desired effect of the Lagrange multipliers. $\lambda$ adjusts the diagonal elements to make the trace zero and $\Lambda$ ultimately subtracts away the antisymmetric components to make the resulting matrix symmetric. This means that in a gradient descent algorithm, adding a multiple of this gradient to any feasible $Q$ will result in another feasible $Q$. However, the difference between this and the parameterization approach is that this equation modifies all $9$ components of the matrix at once without needing to do any parameterization at all. It also produces a steepest descent direction, but now in the $9$-dimensional space of $3\times 3$ matrices. We should therefore not expect the two gradients to give the same values in general since we are looking at the first components of directions that lie in different spaces.

Thank you, this is extremely clarifying. Just to make sure I understand correctly: the phrase "steepest ascent" really means that the directional derivative $\nabla_M F(Q) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(Q + hM)  - F(Q)}{h}$ for $|M| = \text{const}$ is maximized with $M = \nabla_Q G$ (at least for constrained $M$).
If I rig my parameterization such that $\left| V \right| = \left| P(V) \right|$ will it then be true that $P\left( \partial F / \partial V \right) = \nabla_Q G$?


That limit yields $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Q}M$, the Jacobian action on $M$. The gradient is given by the transpose of this Jacobian and the directional derivative is maximized at the gradient. 2. Some of what you have written isn't well-defined but I think the answer is yes but only if they are evaluated at the same matrix $Q = P(V)$. The ambiguity comes when you want to write down a basis for the subspace that isn't orthonormal. The gradient in the subspace is expressed in this basis and hence some components will be added together from the nonorhogonality of the basis elements

